# how to make new tab in terminal alacritty?

Tags: linux, yaml, zsh, gnome-terminal, alacritty

[how to make the alacritty terminal can create new tabs, which has been found that how to create new windows, which I want like a gnome terminal like my screenshoots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dqvlr.png)

how to configure it in alacritty or related documents that I can read, or maybe another terminal that is almost the same iterm2 that can be used in linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are interested in tiling window managers like dwm, you may not need tabs as dwm handles windows differently. Instead, you can manage multiple terminals using workspaces. To launch a new terminal, you can open it within the same workspace and switch between them using keybindings defined in dwm's configuration file.

Keep in mind that another versatile option is using tmux, a terminal multiplexer, which can provide tab-like functionality and much more. It allows you to split your terminal into multiple panes and manage multiple sessions.

Ultimately, the best choice depends on your preferences and workflow. I recommend trying out different options to see which one suits you best.

Comment: yes thanks, alacritty also told me that they don't support multi tabs, because they think it will slow down the performance of the terminal, I didn't read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In the alacritty.yml configuration file, you can set a keybinding for the action, "SpawnNewInstance." I have this set to super+N on linux and cmd+N on mac.

Also, you can set up your desktop shortcut to be something like this:

```
alacritty msg create-window || alacritty
```

This will try to create a new window to use an existing alacritty process, and if there isn't one, it will make a new one.